# CMake Boost linker error

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to build a C++ executable that uses a Boost library. Building with CMake.

CMake snippet:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(main src/cpp/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${BOOST_LIBRARIES})
```

Getting following CMake build error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
...
```

Why am I getting the error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The variables created by the `find_package(Boost ...)` call you are using are case sensitive, i.e.

`${BOOST_LIBRARIES}`

will be empty and you need to make sure you are using it like this:

`${Boost_LIBRARIES}`

The same goes for `Boost_INCLUDES` which you have used (read: copy-pasted) correctly here:

`include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})`

Answer (score 3):

To complete seeekr's answer, you should consider using imported target instead of `Boost_` variables:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system)
add_executable(main ...)
target_link_libraries(main Boost::system)
```

The imported target will handle linkage, include directories, compile definitions, and all needed stuff with a single call.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about that way of doing it. But then that means that I'd have to specify every Boost component dependency individually, as opposed to all of them being handled at once with the ${Boost_LIBRARIES} variable?

Comment: No the dependencies are added transitively: `Boost::system` means here the library and all its dependencies

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I have not expressed myself clearly:

Comment: (pressed ENTER too early, continuing...)
I meant what if I have multiple boost components that I'm using, say: `find_package(Boost REQUIRED system random)`; will I then have to add multiple items with your solution, like this? `target_link_libraries(main Boost::system Boost::random)`

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question. Indeed, if you want to link against multiple items with no implicit dependencies, you will have to add each of them. For a very small project (I mean small in terms of line count), that could be considered redundant with the items listed in `find_package`. For a less small project, that will let you see explicitly the items without searching back what you specified in `find_package`, or let you have multiple targets with different Boost dependencies